# Create user with hostname in MySQL Workbench CE 6

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I am attempting to use MySQL Workbench CE 6's modelling facility (mwb files) to distribute a database schema to my client (in order that he can use the simple "Database / Synchronize" method to update the schema of his local database whenever it changes) but have come up with a problem that I'm not quite sure how to fix.

The problem is that when it creates the user I've specified in the "schema privileges" section, it creates an entry in the mysql.users table that looks like this:

```
host    user    password    [....]
%   worddata    [hashed password]   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N                   0   0   0   0   mysql_native_password       N
```

Unfortunately, because of the flawed way in which mysql authentication works it is actually impossible to log in as this user (because the created-by-default anonymous user at localhost has a higher precedence level, so attempts to log in as this user always resolve to the anonymous user, which has no privileges on the database so is not allowed to connect).  So I therefore need the system to create the user "worddata"@"localhost" instead of "worddata"@"%".  But I don't see any UI for setting the hostname of a user. Is there any way of telling it to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simple. You can add the host part to the user name in the user object editor:

[image]